# After selecting drop down from header how to change the content of other component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I was trying to build a multi-product application.
Using a drop-down in the header, the user can choose which application data to be shown.

Below is the code snip it of my code of my drop-down in header after every click/ change will call the function change Product (passing the selected product name)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="margin-left:-100px;" ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="languageDropDown">
                  <li *ngFor="let a of products " class="dropdown-item text-center" (click)="changeProduct(a)"style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" (click)="isCollapse = !isCollapse">
                      {{a.name}}
                  </li>
              </ul>
```

Here is the function code
Explanation of below code. In this function, I want the values of other function should be changed. I was thinking to call ngOnInit() but seems like the changes are not being reflected until the page is being reloaded manually.   Hence i had to use  window.location.reload() to reload function but this is not an idea solution .

```
 changeProduct(product:Product) {
    this.app=product.name;
    this.cookieService.set('currentAppName',""+product.productCode);
    this.cookieService.set('productID',product.id);
    this.OtherComponent.ngOnInit();
    window.location.reload()
  }
```

Hope someone can suggest me the correct way how to change the other component values after making changes in header in Angular 13

Comment: Use a routerlink and childroutes. Its the Angular way.

Comment: But my other components are also dependent on it. 
values of multiple component are dependent on it. And I have to change the values of all of these.  And I want the values of other component should be changed dynamically @flo

Comment: Ok, so you can use a service to change global data i think.

Comment: @Flo Can you please help me with some example how to implement. 
Also, I was trying to call the ngOnInit() method of other component but doesn't seem right as I want to initialize the values again after the values of header is changed.

Comment: Show me your code of your cookieService and your html files. I will make a sample for you

Comment: For cookies i am using "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2", 
as to set the selected application and accordingly i will display the data of selected application .

HTML - I have mentioned the tag i am using 

@flo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249838/discussion-between-api-and-flo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is a minimal example. The "MyService" hold the value (simple a string in this example). In the AppComponent we bind the value from the service with a `Subscription`. This `Subscription` can be in *every* component/child route what ever you want. So if the value in the service has changed all components get the new value.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-example-uhgq5v?file=app/app.component.html) link.

Greetings, Flo

Comment: Thank you, @flo, for spending time on it. 

I have few doubts,  i was able to implement it , but i am thinking to use it in child components

Comment: in single child i can do like this  inside app-parent . 
<div><app-child [products] = "app"></app-child></div>

 I wanted to know how i can implement below think  using onchange and @Input with router-outlet as all my child components are inside router 
<app-parent>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-parent>

where app-parent is my header and from where i can choose the values and all other components (navbar options)  will be in child